# Pivot table null differentiation problems

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have a table of tests of different types, like this

```
id  lab# testType           result
72  700  Aerobic Plate Count NEG
73  701  Aerobic Plate Count NULL
74  701  E. Coliform         <10
75  701  Total Coliform      20
76  701  Yeast/Mold          NULL
77  702  Aerobic Plate Count NULL
78  702  E. Coliform         NULL
```

I have used this code

```
SELECT
    lab_number,
    MAX(IF(test_type='Aerobic Plate Count',result,NULL)) AS apc,
    MAX(IF(test_type='Total Coliform',result,NULL)) AS tc,
    MAX(IF(test_type='E. Coliform',result,NULL)) AS ec,
    MAX(IF(test_type='Yeat/Mold',result,NULL)) AS ym,
    MAX(IF(test_type='Salmonella VIDAS',result,NULL)) AS sv,
    MAX(IF(test_type='p.H.',result,NULL)) AS ph,
    MAX(IF(test_type='Solids',result,NULL)) AS sl
FROM
    test
group by
    lab_number;
```

to generate a pivot table so that I can easily display all the results and allow them to be edited. Not every test is represented with every type, so a lot of values are NULL. However, results that havent been added in yet are also NULL, **is there a way to differentiate between NULL result and a NULL because of no entry?** I could make the default value for result be something other than NULL, but I'd rather not do that if there is another way.

Comment: There really is no other way, but to change one of the two null values to sg else in the query. null is null. However, your pivot table is not correct, you should use aggregate functions if you have a group by clause, like `min(IF(test_type='Aerobic Plate Count',result,NULL)) AS apc`. Your current query is against the sql standards and would fail on MySQL servers with strict sql mode enabled.

Comment: @Shadow Ah, thank you. I started out having aggregate functions, and I took them out playing around trying to figure out a way to make it work the way I wanted. I have updated the code to the original.

Comment: The answer does not change: null is null. There is no way to differentiate between the 2 nulls, you have to change of the two nulls to something else

Comment: ...one of the two nulls...

Comment: @Shadow alright, you mentioned changing the null within the query. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: nevermind, I got it Thank you!